# How to disable warning logs during LOAD DATA?

Tags: mysql, load-data-infile

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'sample.csv' IGNORE INTO TABLE mytable;
```

Result is ok, but each row logs a warning:

```
| Warning | 1261 | Row 1 doesn't contain data for all columns |
| Warning | 1261 | Row ... doesn't contain data for all columns |
| Warning | 1261 | Row 20000000 doesn't contain data for all columns |
```

But I'm fine with the import and even want to prevent the warning logs (eg they might impact performance). How can I disable those explicit?

Comment: I really see no point doing this. If all rows thows this warning you should consider fixing you csv or the table itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While this isn't the ideal solution you could disable logging warnings for the database.
You could try use

```
SET GLOBAL LOG_WARNINGS = 0
```

to turn off logging and

```
SET GLOBAL LOG_WARNINGS = 1
```

to turn it back on.

Maybe run this before you load your file and then switch it back on afterwards.

UPDATE:
LOG_WARNINGS is deprecated so you can use this:

```
SET GLOBAL log_error_verbosity = 1;
```

which will only log errors. You can set the value to 3 (default value) afterwards.

Here is a reference: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_log_error_verbosity

Comment: `ERROR 1193 (HY000) at line 4: Unknown system variable 'log_warnings'`